# What is difference between Jenkins Shared Libraries and Jenkins pipeline templates

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-template-engine

I am trying to understand what is exact difference between Jenkins Shared Libraries and Jenkins pipeline templates.

Shared libraries as I understand is used for keeping common code and making it accessible to multiple pipelines.

I am not able to understand then what is difference between Jenkins pipeline template. Also what is the use of Jenkins templates created using template engine. Is it somehow similar to shared library

Answer (score 2):

maintainer of the Jenkins Templating Engine here.

### Shared Libraries

Focused on reusing pipeline code. A Jenkinsfile is still required for each individual application and those individual pipelines have to import the libraries.

### Jenkins Templating Engine

A pipeline development *framework* that enables tool-agnostic pipeline templates.

Rather than creating individual Jenkinsfiles, you can create a centralized set of pipeline templates.

These templates invoke `steps` such as:

```
build()
unit_test()
deploy_to dev
```

This **common template** can be applied across teams, regardless of the technology they're using.

The `build`, `unit_test`, and `deploy_to` steps would come from libraries.

There may be multiple libraries that implement the `build` step, such as npm, gradle, maven, etc.

Rather than have each team define an entire pipeline, they can now just declare the tools that should be used to "hydrate" the template via a pipeline configuration file:

```
libraries{
  npm // contributes the build step
}
```

Feel free to check out this [CDF Webinar: Pipeline Templating with the Jenkins Templating Engine](https://youtu.be/FYLaoqn0pDE).